# String safe functions vs security enhanced CRT

Tags: c, windows, string, winapi, strsafe

Are the StringCch* functions considered safer then the safe versions of the CRT string functions.

Is StringCchCatW safer then wcscat_s? Or StringCchCopyW vs wcscpy_s?

Comment: Safer from what? What is your context? Where does the data come from? And did you mean to tag this C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tagged C++, so you should not use either of them, but `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: What about the cases when you have to receive a string from a windows api function, append just a new line, and pass it to another api function. Is it really better to convert it to a `std::wstring`, then append the new line, and pass the c_str() to the api function?

Comment: @Josh: Yes. Also, you can use `wstring` or `vector<wchar_t>` for temporary buffers just fine.

Comment: Using vector<> tends to invite buffer overrun, just as C string code does.

Comment: Would you care to explain a little why using `std::wstring` is better in these situations?

Comment: Would you care to explain what dangers you are concerned about? My guess is buffer overruns. And string/wstring make it easy for you to avoid them.

Comment: But doesn't the security enhanced C string functions also make it easy prevent them? Also what other security vulnerabilities exist in strings other than buffer overruns?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you are dealing with strings in your application.

With the Windows SDK many people end up mixing a lot of c-runtime, and windows api calls - because the windows api is a C API layered on top of the c-runtime it is difficult for windows programmers to know they are doing this, and why it is (potentially) wrong.

But, basically, at some point of your application development, you really should choose where you are going to get your basic data types from. Especially in the case of string data as the localization apis, that effect sorting, collation and so on are quite different.

You can choose to use the c-runtimes string support. This involves using strings that are typed as "const char*" or wchar_t. Microsoft's c-runtime specifically (it is possible to develop windows applications with GCC, so this distinction can be important if you want to write code that compiles on multiple compilers) offers a set of functions in , based off storing text data in _TCHAR's, and using the _MBCS and _UNICODE macros to switch the functions from single character, to multi byte character to wide character supporting versions.

If you choose to use the c-runtimes string abstractions, then using the c-runtimes "safe" string routnes would make the most sense.

Alternatively, Windows GUI applications frequently choose to use the windows SDK data types: CHAR, INT, WCHAR, TCHAR, DWORD etc. Strings, would be represented by LPCTSTR variables usually, and in this case, continuing to use the windows abstractions, SafeStringCch etc. make the most sense.

Really, the worst thing you can do in a program is keep on bouncing between using windows API calls, and c-runtime calls, as they have different rules sometimes for how they deal with edge cases... and this can lead to some very hard to spot bugs.